# Get repository "created by" details using azure devops api

Tags: git, api, azure-devops, repository

I want to get the details of who has created the repository in the Azure devops project.
I am calling this API found in Microsoft document [Get repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get%20repository?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but this API is returning only limited details: I need created by details also (who has created this repo).

I could not find any other API which returns my desired details.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a repository, you can go back to the first commit and see when and by who it was made.

Comment: What if repo is just created and don't have any commit yet.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852290/how-to-get-azure-devops-repository-creation-date-via-api) maybe this helps